# Spark & PySpark: table-level access control?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We're trying to enable different groups use spark/pyspark to access data in HDFS.

The data access in Hive/Presto is controlled by `Apache Ranger`, so some sensitive data can be better protected.

However, after some search, I didn't find many things related to spark's access control (at table level). And some commercial distribution has built their on, such as https://docs.databricks.com/administration-guide/access-control/table-acls/table-acl.html

---

My questions

- How to do table-level access control for spark/pyspark, under env such as `Zeppelin`, `Jupyter`?
- Is there any solution with `Apache Ranger` or `Apache Sentry`?
- If I have to implement myself, where should I start?

Thanks!

Comment: Hive data files are stored in specific HDFS directories. Ranger and Sentry can control access privileges at **HDFS** level, but it's your responsibility to map Hive tables to HDFS directories, and Hive privs to HDFS privs.

Comment: Note that using Ranger/Sentry instead of raw HDFS ACLs is a nice workaround to the stupid HDFS bug (solved in Hadoop 3.x) about ACL inheritance >> https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6962

Comment: From the top of my mind, I'd say that Sentry sets (and checks) HDFS ACLs and lets the NameNode manage the access control, while Ranger intercepts all access requests and adds its own filters on top of raw ACLs. But I wouldn't bet any money on that.

Comment: About POSIX Access Control Lists (ACL) -- same concept in HDFS and in the Linux file system >> https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#ACLs_.28Access_Control_Lists.29